# How to display html link element inside php script

Tags: php, html

I am trying to include a php variable inside this php script that displays an html link. What i need is to include my php $row['vin'] variable in the href html link after the ? to pass a value to the page i am linking to. Top code block works but i still need that php variable, bottom is an example of what ive tried which will not work.

Works but missing my php variable:

```
 <?php if($row['instock'] == "Yes")
    {
         echo '<a href="orderForm.php?">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true">
         </span>
         </a>';
    }
    ?>
```

Does not work:

```
<td>
<?php if($row['instock'] == "Yes")
{
      echo '<a href="orderForm.php?'. $row['vin']">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true">
      </span>
      </a>';
}
?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten the rest of the concatenation logic. It's just a syntax error:

```
<td>
<?php if($row['instock'] == "Yes")
{
      echo '<a href="orderForm.php?'. $row['vin'] . '">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true">
      </span>
      </a>';
}
?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using PHP to `echo` out great chunks of mostly static content is to instead, drop in and out of the PHP context (ie `<?php ... ?>`) when necessary and use it like a templating language.

For example

```php
<td>
  <?php if ($row['instock'] == "Yes"): ?>
    <a href="orderForm.php?<?= htmlspecialchars($row['vin']) ?>">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
  <?php endif ?>
</td>
```

See http://php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php